# How to use an exponent that contains a variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, induction

I am trying to understand a problem that uses mathematical induction to prove the validity of a statement. This is how one section moves to another:
$$
2k + 3 = 2^{k + 1}
$$
$$
2k + 3 = (2k + 1) + 2
$$

can someone explain this to me?

Here is the proof:

Theorem: For all integers $n\geq 3$, $2n + 1 < 2^n$.

I need to show how that for all integers $k\geq3$, if $P(k)$ is true then $P(k+1)$ is also true:
$$
2n + 1 < 2^{n}
$$
$$
2k+1<2k \\ (\text{the inductive hypothesis})
$$
$$
2(k+1)+1<2^{k+1} \\ (\text{the $k+1$ term}) \\
$$

$$
$$
**Body of Proof:**
$$
2k + 3 = 2^{k + 1}
$$
$$
2k + 3 = (2k + 1) + 2
$$
$$
<2^{k}  + 2^{k}
$$
$$
\therefore 2k+3<2 \cdot 2^{k} = 2^{k+1}
$$

Comment: I think more context of the problem is needed...

Comment: ok ill edit the post....

Comment: You need a lot more **text** in your question that describes what it is you're doing. Just dumping bag of random formulas onto the reader isn't going to help anyone understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: my question is about the mechanics of the proof. These are all of the steps in the proof. The theorum, the inductive hypothesis, the term i need to solve for (k+1) and the body of the proof. I don't understand how the proof works so I'm not sure how I can better describe it.

Answer (score 0):

So the proposition, $P(n)$ is $2n + 1 < 2^n$ for all $n\ge 3$.

So first you show the **initial step** that if $k = 3$ that $P(k)$ is true.

That's easy to show.  You just to do it.  $2(3) + 1 = 7 < 8 = 2^3$.  It's true.

Now the  **induction step**

We must show that for any $k$ so that $P(k)$ is true, (for example if $k = 3$) then it can be proven that for that particular $k$ that $P(k)$ is true.

So if $P(k)$ is true then we take it as a given that $k$ is a specific number so that $2k + 1 < 2^k$.  That's a given.

We need to prove that $2(k+1) + 1 < 2^{k+1}$.

Okay.  $2(k+1) +1 = 2k + 2 + 1 = 2k+3$.  And $2^{k+1} = 2^k*2$.

Can we combine those to prove $2k+3 < 2^k*2$?

We can because we were given that $2k + 1 < 2^k$

Proof:  $2(k+1) + 1 =$

$2k + 3 = $

$(2k + 1) + 2$.  We were given that $2k + 1 < 2^k$ so

$(2k + 1) + 2 < 2^k + 2$.  Now we know that as $k \ge 3 > 1$ that $2^k > 2$. so

$2^k + 2 < 2^k + 2^k$

$= 2*2^k$

$= 2^{k+1}$

So to reiterate:

$$2(k+1)+1=(2k+1) + 2< 2^k +2 < 2^k + 2^k=2*2^k = 2^{k+1}$$

And that's it we are done.

We have proven that 1) $P(k)$ is true for $k = 3$ and  2) if $P(k)$ is true for any particular $k$ (such as $k = 3$) then $P(k+1)$ is also true (so we know it is true for $4$, and therefore it is true for $4+1 = 5$, etc.).  From induction principal we can conclude $P(n)$ is true for all $n \ge 3$.

Comment: Argh!!!!!! Another zombie thread!!!!!!!  (Kind of curious why no one ever answered it though....)